# Leaflet: check if object is Path or Marker

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have the following code to add a GeoJSON layer to a map using Mapbox.js (which of course is built on Leaflet.js):

```
var orgLayer = L.geoJson(boundaries, {
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature
});
this.layerGroup.addLayer(orgLayer);

function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    layer.on('click', zoomToFeature, _this);
}
function zoomToFeature(e) {
    this.map.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
}
```

The problem I'm having is that the GeoJSON may consist of Polygons or Points, and hence Leaflet renders the layer as either Paths or Markers. When it's Polygons (Paths), this all works fine. When it's Points (Markers), the code fails on `e.target.getBounds()`.

This is understandable because `getBounds` is only a method on Path in Leaflet, not on [Marker](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#marker). I guess for Marker I can use `e.target.getLatLng()`.

However, how can I adapt my code to check whether the target is a Marker or  a Path, and use the correct method?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can write some code that involves the use of [instanceof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) to check if the layer is an instance of the L.Path or L.Marker class.

For example:

```
if (layer instanceof L.Marker) {
    //do something
} else if (layer instanceof L.Path) {
    //do something else
}
```